# Counting "subcolumns" with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Guys let me make myself clear. I'm studying MYSQL and practicing the function "count()". I have a table called "City", where I have ID, name, CountryCode, district, and Population. My first idea was to know how many cities I have by country

`SELECT *, Count(name) as "total" FROM world.city GROUP BY countrycode;`

It worked, an extra column was created with the number of cities by each country. I would like to know how many countries I have by counting the number of distinct rows (I know that a have this information on the bottom of the WorkBench, but I would like to know to make this information appear on my query). I tried to add a Count(CountryCode), but it didn't work as I was expecting, a number 4079 appeared, which is the total number of cities that I have. I figured out that my "Count()" is calculating the number of rows inside each Country, not counting the number of codes that I have for each country. Is that possible to get this information?

Comment: Your query should give an error since you are selecting all columns but only grouping by one

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT countrycode) FROM world.city`

Answer (score 1):

(A mini-lesson for a Novice.)

- The first thing to learn is that `COUNT(*)` is the usual way to use `COUNT`.  And you get the number of *rows*.  In contrast, `COUNT(name)` counts the number of rows with non-NULL `name` values.
- Then comes the way to use `DISTINCT`.  It is not a function.  So `COUNT(DISTINCT a,b)` counts the number of different combinations of `a` and `b`.  And `COUNT(DISTINCT(a))` though it works 'fine' and 'correctly', the parens are redundant.  So use `COUNT(DISTINCT a)`.
- Don't use `*` with `GROUP BY`.  That is, `SELECT *, ... GROUP BY ...` is improper.  The usual way to say something like your query is

  SELECT countrycode, COUNT(*) AS "total"
  FROM world.city
  GROUP BY countrycode;

For provinces in Canada (which I happen to have a table of):

```
SELECT province, COUNT(*) AS "total" FROM world.canada GROUP BY province;

+---------------------------+-------+
| province                  | total |
+---------------------------+-------+
| Alberta                   |   573 |
| British Columbia          |   716 |
| Manitoba                  |   299 |
| New Brunswick             |   210 |
| Newfoundland and Labrador |   474 |
| Northwest Territories     |    94 |
| Nova Scotia               |   331 |
| Nunavut                   |   107 |
| Ontario                   |   891 |
| Prince Edward Island      |    57 |
| Quebec                    |  1045 |
| Saskatchewan              |   573 |
| Yukon                     |   114 |
+---------------------------+-------+
```

Note that a few cities show up in multiple provinces:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT city), COUNT(*) FROM world.canada;
+----------------------+----------+
| COUNT(DISTINCT city) | COUNT(*) |
+----------------------+----------+
|                 5248 |     5484 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

- Munch on this; there are some more lessons to learn:

  ```
    SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS ct, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT state)
             FROM world.us
             GROUP BY city
             ORDER BY COUNT(*)
             DESC LIMIT 11;
    +-------------+----+----------------------------------+
    | city        | ct | GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT state)     |
    +-------------+----+----------------------------------+
    | Springfield | 11 | FL,IL,MA,MO,NJ,OH,OR,PA,TN,VA,VT |
    | Clinton     | 10 | CT,IA,MA,MD,MO,MS,OK,SC,TN,UT    |
    | Madison     |  8 | AL,CT,IN,ME,MS,NJ,SD,WI          |
    | Lebanon     |  8 | IN,ME,MO,NH,OH,OR,PA,TN          |
    | Auburn      |  7 | AL,CA,IN,ME,NH,NY,WA             |
    | Burlington  |  7 | IA,MA,NC,NJ,VT,WA,WI             |
    | Washington  |  7 | DC,IL,IN,MO,NC,PA,UT             |
    | Farmington  |  7 | ME,MI,MN,MO,NH,NM,UT             |
    | Canton      |  6 | GA,IL,MA,MI,MS,OH                |
    | Monroe      |  6 | GA,LA,MI,NC,WA,WI                |
    | Lancaster   |  6 | CA,NY,OH,PA,SC,TX                |
    +-------------+----+----------------------------------+
  ```
- As for the number of cities in a country, that belongs in a the table `Countries`, not in the table `Cities`.  Then use a `JOIN` when you want to put them together.

Comment: PS -- My data says there are 57 cities named "Mala" in 39 countries.  And 317 San Antonio's in 28 countries.